# В Kivy как отобразить Image виджеты(и не только) на второй странице(Screen)? Python

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

Прошу помощи с кодом.
С первой странице через кнопку переходим на вторую, куда на виджет Image с помощью функции `video` идёт поток изображений с вебкамеры.
У меня не получается "ухватиться" за виджет - выпадает такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
KeyError: 'vid'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\kivy\test.py", line 60, in <module>
    TestApp().run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 956, in run
    runTouchApp()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
    EventLoop.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in mainloop
    self.idle()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 379, in idle
    Clock.tick()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 733, in tick
    self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
    self._process_events()
  File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 620, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
  File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 653, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
  File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
  File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
  File "F:\kivy\test.py", line 56, in video
    self.root.ids.vid.image.texture = img_texture # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

или такая:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'texture'
```

Вот код с .py:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App

import cv2

#Config.set('graphics', 'width', 1024)
#Config.set('graphics', 'height', 720)


class ScreenMain(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenVideo(Screen):
    image = ObjectProperty(None)
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('test.kv')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = WindowManager()
        sm.add_widget(ScreenMain(name='main_screen'))
        sm.add_widget(ScreenVideo(name='video_screen'))
        self.screen_video = ScreenVideo()
        return sm

    def loop(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.video, 1)

    def video(self, *args):

        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        ret, frame = capture.read()

        # capture.set(3, 480)
        # capture.set(4, 640)

        buf = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()

        img_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        img_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        self.root.ids.vid.image.texture = img_texture # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
        # self.screen_video.image.texture = img_texture   # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'texture'
        #self.root.ids.vid.image.remove_from_cache()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

.kv файл:

```
WindowManager:
    ScreenMain:
        id: main
    ScreenVideo:
        id: vid


<ScreenMain>:
    name: "main_screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "something"
        Button:
            text: 'Next screen'
            on_release:
                app.loop()
                app.root.current = "video_screen"

<ScreenVideo>:
    name: "video_screen"
    BoxLayout:

        image: image

        Image:
            id: image
```